# Difference between EA and RUP 4+1?

Tags: rup, enterprise-architecture

What is the difference between Enterprise architecture and RUP (Rational Unified Process) 4+1 view on arcitecture?

Is it similar alternative to EA or its the same?

IMHO EA = business + information + technology + applications

while the 4+1 RUP architecture is connected only to the IT of an company, not needed to solve IT Governance etc.
What do you think?

Comment: The connection between 4+1 and RUP is that 4+1 was designed by Philippe Kruchten, who was a Director of Process Development at Rational. The 4+1 model is not the only way of satisfying the inception and elaboration phase activities related to architectural design in RUP. Comparing EA to RUP doesn't make sense to me - one is an approach to planning, analysis, design, and implementation of systems (human and IT) in an organization and the other is a process. Comparing EA and 4+1 also doesn't make sense as one just provides a method of organizing information. What are you trying to solve?

Comment: I am trying to distinct all abstract definitions of Architecture, IT Architecture, Business Architecture etc.

Comment: Have you started with Wikipedia? I took a quick look, and their articles on [software architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_architecture), [information technology architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_technology_architecture), [enterprise architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_architecture), and the various linked pages all look pretty clear to me. After doing research and reading from various sources, what specifically is confusing you? What problems are you having in understanding these concepts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EA has some frameworks for describing some levels of organisations. These levels are strategies, business process, IT services and technologies for that services. EA frameworks have activities and artifacts for representing these levels. In fact, after applying EA, we have some descriptions of "services" or "application" for supporting business processes of organizations. Now for implementing each service or application, we use "RUP 4+1 view" for representing the "architecture" of that system. 
In fact, this concepts can link to each other for implementing the service of the organization.